# Decrypting/Decoding encrypted/encoded data

Tags: encryption, character-encoding, cryptography, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to increase the interoperability of some database software. The database can write and read "stored SQL queries". I wanted to figure out the format of these SQL queries so I can build them outside the application.

I started out with some data gathering:

```
"A"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 3a c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 3a 0f f7
"B"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 3a c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 60 0f f8
"C"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 3a c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 86 0f f9
"D"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 ba c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 ac 0f fa
"E"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 ba c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 d2 0f fb
"F"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 ba c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 99 f8 0f fc
"G"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 ba c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a 1e 0f fd
"H"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 7a c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a 44 0f fe
"I"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 7a c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a 6a 0f ff
"J"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 7a c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a 90 10 00
"K"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 7a c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a b6 10 01
"L"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 fa c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9a dc 10 02
"M"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 fa c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b 02 10 03
"N"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 fa c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b 28 10 04
"O"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 fa c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b 4e 10 05
"P"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 06 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b 74 10 06
"Q"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 06 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b 9a 10 07
"R"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 06 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b c0 10 08
"S"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 06 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9b e6 10 09
"T"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 86 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c 0c 10 0a
"U"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 86 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c 32 10 0b
"V"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 86 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c 58 10 0c
"W"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 86 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c 7e 10 0d
"X"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 46 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c a4 10 0e
"Y"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 46 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c ca 10 0f
"Z"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 46 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9c f0 10 10
"a"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 26 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9d fa 10 17
"b"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 26 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e 20 10 18
"c"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 26 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e 46 10 19
"d"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 a6 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e 6c 10 1a
"e"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 a6 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e 92 10 1b
"f"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 a6 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e b8 10 1c
"g"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 a6 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9e de 10 1d
"h"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 66 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f 04 10 1e
"i"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 66 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f 2a 10 1f
"j"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 66 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f 50 10 20
"k"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 66 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f 76 10 21
"l"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 e6 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f 9c 10 22
"m"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 e6 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f c2 10 23
"n"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 e6 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 9f e8 10 24
"o"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 e6 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 0e 10 25
"p"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 16 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 34 10 26
"q"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 16 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 5a 10 27
"r"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 16 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 80 10 28
"s"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 16 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 a6 10 29
"t"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 96 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 cc 10 2a
"u"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 96 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a0 f2 10 2b
"v"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 96 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a1 18 10 2c
"w"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 96 c3 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a1 3e 10 2d
"x"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 56 c0 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a1 64 10 2e
"y"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 56 c2 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a1 8a 10 2f
"z"      ff aa 01 01 50 00 00 00 78 01 63 64 40 05 ff ff fd e7 4c 64 c8 01 c2 78 20 ce 64 c8 63 c8 66 28 66 00 8a 32 56 c1 15 02 79 20 11 38 1f c6 60 04 32 00 a1 b0 10 30
```

Above we have the quoted-contents of the stored query (left) and the BLOB data converted to hex (right).

Most of the contents is unaltered, so let's start by trimming the strings down to strictly the bytes that change:

```
"A"     ...   3a c2   ...   99 3a 0f f7
"B"     ...   3a c1   ...   99 60 0f f8
"C"     ...   3a c3   ...   99 86 0f f9
"D"     ...   ba c0   ...   99 ac 0f fa
"E"     ...   ba c2   ...   99 d2 0f fb
"F"     ...   ba c1   ...   99 f8 0f fc
"G"     ...   ba c3   ...   9a 1e 0f fd
"H"     ...   7a c0   ...   9a 44 0f fe
"I"     ...   7a c2   ...   9a 6a 0f ff
"J"     ...   7a c1   ...   9a 90 10 00
"K"     ...   7a c3   ...   9a b6 10 01
"L"     ...   fa c0   ...   9a dc 10 02
"M"     ...   fa c2   ...   9b 02 10 03
"N"     ...   fa c1   ...   9b 28 10 04
"O"     ...   fa c3   ...   9b 4e 10 05
"P"     ...   06 c0   ...   9b 74 10 06
"Q"     ...   06 c2   ...   9b 9a 10 07
"R"     ...   06 c1   ...   9b c0 10 08
"S"     ...   06 c3   ...   9b e6 10 09
"T"     ...   86 c0   ...   9c 0c 10 0a
"U"     ...   86 c2   ...   9c 32 10 0b
"V"     ...   86 c1   ...   9c 58 10 0c
"W"     ...   86 c3   ...   9c 7e 10 0d
"X"     ...   46 c0   ...   9c a4 10 0e
"Y"     ...   46 c2   ...   9c ca 10 0f
"Z"     ...   46 c1   ...   9c f0 10 10
"a"     ...   26 c2   ...   9d fa 10 17
"b"     ...   26 c1   ...   9e 20 10 18
"c"     ...   26 c3   ...   9e 46 10 19
"d"     ...   a6 c0   ...   9e 6c 10 1a
"e"     ...   a6 c2   ...   9e 92 10 1b
"f"     ...   a6 c1   ...   9e b8 10 1c
"g"     ...   a6 c3   ...   9e de 10 1d
"h"     ...   66 c0   ...   9f 04 10 1e
"i"     ...   66 c2   ...   9f 2a 10 1f
"j"     ...   66 c1   ...   9f 50 10 20
"k"     ...   66 c3   ...   9f 76 10 21
"l"     ...   e6 c0   ...   9f 9c 10 22
"m"     ...   e6 c2   ...   9f c2 10 23
"n"     ...   e6 c1   ...   9f e8 10 24
"o"     ...   e6 c3   ...   a0 0e 10 25
"p"     ...   16 c0   ...   a0 34 10 26
"q"     ...   16 c2   ...   a0 5a 10 27
"r"     ...   16 c1   ...   a0 80 10 28
"s"     ...   16 c3   ...   a0 a6 10 29
"t"     ...   96 c0   ...   a0 cc 10 2a
"u"     ...   96 c2   ...   a0 f2 10 2b
"v"     ...   96 c1   ...   a1 18 10 2c
"w"     ...   96 c3   ...   a1 3e 10 2d
"x"     ...   56 c0   ...   a1 64 10 2e
"y"     ...   56 c2   ...   a1 8a 10 2f
"z"     ...   56 c1   ...   a1 b0 10 30
```

Even though this is a fairly large sample of characters (though of course not all 256 ASCII characters) I can't really see a pattern between any of the rows.

Another way to look at the data:

```
"A"     ...   3a c2   ...   99 3a 0f f7    |    "a"     ...   26 c2   ...   9d fa 10 17
"B"     ...   3a c1   ...   99 60 0f f8    |    "b"     ...   26 c1   ...   9e 20 10 18
"C"     ...   3a c3   ...   99 86 0f f9    |    "c"     ...   26 c3   ...   9e 46 10 19
"D"     ...   ba c0   ...   99 ac 0f fa    |    "d"     ...   a6 c0   ...   9e 6c 10 1a
"E"     ...   ba c2   ...   99 d2 0f fb    |    "e"     ...   a6 c2   ...   9e 92 10 1b
"F"     ...   ba c1   ...   99 f8 0f fc    |    "f"     ...   a6 c1   ...   9e b8 10 1c
"G"     ...   ba c3   ...   9a 1e 0f fd    |    "g"     ...   a6 c3   ...   9e de 10 1d
"H"     ...   7a c0   ...   9a 44 0f fe    |    "h"     ...   66 c0   ...   9f 04 10 1e
"I"     ...   7a c2   ...   9a 6a 0f ff    |    "i"     ...   66 c2   ...   9f 2a 10 1f
"J"     ...   7a c1   ...   9a 90 10 00    |    "j"     ...   66 c1   ...   9f 50 10 20
"K"     ...   7a c3   ...   9a b6 10 01    |    "k"     ...   66 c3   ...   9f 76 10 21
"L"     ...   fa c0   ...   9a dc 10 02    |    "l"     ...   e6 c0   ...   9f 9c 10 22
"M"     ...   fa c2   ...   9b 02 10 03    |    "m"     ...   e6 c2   ...   9f c2 10 23
"N"     ...   fa c1   ...   9b 28 10 04    |    "n"     ...   e6 c1   ...   9f e8 10 24   
"O"     ...   fa c3   ...   9b 4e 10 05    |    "o"     ...   e6 c3   ...   a0 0e 10 25
"P"     ...   06 c0   ...   9b 74 10 06    |    "p"     ...   16 c0   ...   a0 34 10 26
"Q"     ...   06 c2   ...   9b 9a 10 07    |    "q"     ...   16 c2   ...   a0 5a 10 27
"R"     ...   06 c1   ...   9b c0 10 08    |    "r"     ...   16 c1   ...   a0 80 10 28
"S"     ...   06 c3   ...   9b e6 10 09    |    "s"     ...   16 c3   ...   a0 a6 10 29
"T"     ...   86 c0   ...   9c 0c 10 0a    |    "t"     ...   96 c0   ...   a0 cc 10 2a
"U"     ...   86 c2   ...   9c 32 10 0b    |    "u"     ...   96 c2   ...   a0 f2 10 2b
"V"     ...   86 c1   ...   9c 58 10 0c    |    "v"     ...   96 c1   ...   a1 18 10 2c
"W"     ...   86 c3   ...   9c 7e 10 0d    |    "w"     ...   96 c3   ...   a1 3e 10 2d
"X"     ...   46 c0   ...   9c a4 10 0e    |    "x"     ...   56 c0   ...   a1 64 10 2e
"Y"     ...   46 c2   ...   9c ca 10 0f    |    "y"     ...   56 c2   ...   a1 8a 10 2f
"Z"     ...   46 c1   ...   9c f0 10 10    |    "z"     ...   56 c1   ...   a1 b0 10 30
```

Interestingly the 2nd byte of the first altering section appears to be consistent across all A-Z and a-z. The 1st byte however only shares a moderate pattern though P-Z and p-z.

The final altering sections seem almost like completely arbitrary characters. Perhaps one part is a key and the other part is an encoded/encrypted character?

I also briefly took a look at the following:

```
"a"     ...   26 c2 15 02 79 20 11         ...   9d fa 10 17
"aa"    ...   25 32 24 c2 95 02 f9 20 31   ...   c0 c5 10 79
```

And that's where I stopped researching... I am yet to spot the pattern which links all this data together. I can't help but feel there is an easier way to solve this mystery but I currently just lack the knowledge to obtain the answer.

1. Can anyone suggest a better method of cracking this code?
2. What data will I need to crack the code? Fortunately I can just mass produce this data...

Comment: The best way to do this is to do it the other way around. I presume the format isn't secret, so why not try and find a description of it somewhere?

Comment: Well that's part of the problem. It is secret. Or rather "Not in the scope of support" and "SQL\d+Blob.dat" doesn't give much to go on...